# Can not connect with mysql in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using MySQL database in node.js application but can't connect with MySQL. I just changed the XAMPP server port 80 to 600, but what's the problem in MySQL connection?

Connection node.js code:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  port     : '3306',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database :'appdb'
});
```

Request headers:

```
Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Host    localhost:1337
Referer http://localhost:1337/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Throwing error message:

> module.js:340 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'D:\project\hotel\app.js' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) at startup (node.js:119:16) at node.js:902:3

Comment: 80 ? Are you sure this wasn't a port used for http based managment ? Default MySQL port is 3306.

Comment: default port is not working...........

Comment: Please don't post any error messages that you're getting, let us guess what's wrong.

Comment: sorry bro. i m using visaul studion node js plugin...if manauly throw command then show the following error :

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^


Error: Cannot find module 'D:\project\hotel\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the port of your xamp server, but the port of your mysql server (usually 3306).

Comment: default port is ok and i allready checked. but i just changed the server port but application can't established the mysql connection.